# Connecting the higher energies of GP and KdV via a Riccati equation

Tags: co.combinatorics, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, integrable-systems

I will describe my set-up and then the problem.
We use the branch of the complex square root where
$$ \sqrt{re^{i \phi}} = \sqrt{r} e^{i \frac{\phi}{2}} \qquad \forall r > 0 \,, \forall \phi \in [0, 2 \pi). $$

Let $u, v \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$ be real-valued Schwartz functions. Let $\epsilon > 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y \in \mathbb{C}$ with $Re Y < 0$. We consider the Riccati-type equation

$$
0 = - M_x + Y M - \frac12 (M^2 + (\sigma_1 M)^2)
+ \begin{pmatrix}
    - u - \frac{\epsilon^2 v}{2} &
    i \Big( v - \frac{\epsilon^2 v}{2} - \frac{\epsilon^2 Y^2}{4} (u + v) \Big) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{\epsilon^2 Y^2}{2}}} \\
    i \Big( - u - \frac{\epsilon^2 v}{2} + \frac{\epsilon^2 Y^2}{4} (u + v) \Big) \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{\epsilon^2 Y^2}{2}}} &
    v - \frac{\epsilon^2 v}{2} 
\end{pmatrix} $$

for $M(x, Y; \epsilon) \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ with vanishing boundary condition at $|Y| = \infty$. Here $\sigma_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
A solution can be found via the Ansatz

$$ 
   M(x, Y; \epsilon) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{M_n(x; \epsilon)}{Y^n} .
$$

This yields an iterative formula for the $M_n$, which may then be computed.

I have symbolically verified the following claim for many iterations:
Consider the solutions $\phi(x, Y; \epsilon), \psi(x, Y; \epsilon) \in \mathbb{C}$ to the Riccati-type equations

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
    0 &= - \phi_x + Y \phi - \phi^2 - u \\
    0 &= - \psi_x + Y \psi - \psi^2 + v .
\end{array}
$$

Expanding

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
    \phi(x, Y; \epsilon) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\phi_n(x; \epsilon)}{Y^n}  \\
    \psi(x, Y; \epsilon) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\psi_n(x; \epsilon)}{Y^n} ,
\end{array}
$$

we find that

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
    (M_n)_{1,1} &= \phi_n + O(\epsilon^2) \\
    (M_n)_{2,2} &= \psi_n + O(\epsilon^2) .
\end{array}
$$
**I could not prove this.** At first I attempted using the iterative formulations for $M_n, \phi_n, \psi_n$ for an inductive proof, but the situation is far too messy. Non-trivial cancellations happen. This is why I went back to the generating functions, hoping for an analytical approach.

**Why is this interesting?**

Up to a term which I have negleted for simplicity, the integrals $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} M_n(x; \epsilon) \,dx $$ are conserved quantities for the hydrodynamic Gross-Pitaevskii equation $$i \partial_t q + \partial_{xx} q = 2 q (|q|^2 - 1), $$ where $u$ and $v$ obtained from $q$ by a change of variables and some rescaling with $\epsilon$. These variables $u$ and $v$ are expected to approximately solve the KdV equation, and indeed there are results (See Bethuel, Gravejat, Saut, Smets). It has previously been discovered that the first couple of KdV-energies of $u$ and $v$ are conserved up to an error $O(\epsilon^2)$. Solving the above problem would lead to a proof that this holds for all the higher energies.

Comment: Why the Combinatorics tag?

Comment: I previously spent a lot of time with the iterative formulation. It is a bit of a Catalan type recursion. It's probably not really combinatorics, but you can formulate the problem as "Given this recursive sequence of polynomials, show this formula holds".